# Python plt.colorbar() what does it do and what does the numbers on colorbar signifies?

Tags: python, matplotlib, visualization

Can someone explain to me what and how colorbar is used? I dont get the significance of colorbar and the number is it shows? What does the number on colorbar means? Please explain to me...
Data is from datacamp: Two columns with percentage of students taking biology and business from year 1970 to 2010. Below code makes a 2dhist but I dont understand what colorbar labels signifies? is it percentage??

```
plt.hist2d(data['Biology'], data['Business'], bins=(5,5))
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

[image: image here]

Comment: They are the colors you have passed into `plt.scatter`. You can see them using `print(colors)`

Comment: @bongwater05 see my answer and let me know

Comment: @bongwater05 have a look on the size of your data. here the color represent for the number of data point per bin

Comment: the colors are the counts/frequency of each bin. See the last paragraph in my answer.

Answer (score 5):

You have not uploaded your data so I am going to post a toy example and explain some things.

```
from matplotlib.colors import LogNorm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(0)

# normal distribution center at x=0 and y=5
x = np.random.randn(100000)
y = np.random.randn(100000) + 5

plt.hist2d(x, y, bins=40, norm=LogNorm())
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
cbar = plt.colorbar()
cbar.ax.set_ylabel('Counts')
plt.show()
```

[image]
Here, I have created 2 variables. The `x` has `mean=0` and the `y` has `mean=5`.
When you plot the 2D hist, you see a 2D histogram. Think about it like looking at a histogram from the "top".

```
print(x.mean())
print(y.mean())
#0.0015767005081253399
#5.005093241323296
```

Now, you can see that the colors at the center of this 2D histogram are yellowish and correspond to the highest values of the colorbar.

This is reasonable since the `histogram of x should have a peak at 0` and the `histogram of y should have a peak at 5`.

You plot their positions on the x-y plane and as you can see they are so dense and overlap with each other. You want to view the distribution better by count of boxes in the plane, so you try a 2D diagram.

### This is exactly what the colors and the colorbar's values mean. It's the height/frequency/counts of each bin if you had a 1D classical histogram.

---

**EDIT 1: By using fewer bins it's like zooming in the initial plot.**

```
from matplotlib.colors import LogNorm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(0)

# normal distribution center at x=0 and y=5
x = np.random.randn(100000)
y = np.random.randn(100000) + 5

plt.hist2d(x, y, bins=(5,5), norm=LogNorm())
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
cbar = plt.colorbar()
cbar.ax.set_ylabel('Counts')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, @seralouk. I was expecting the frequency bin logic but could not find that answer anywhere explicitly mentioning it. Was scratching my head...Thanks a lot.

Comment: hello. happy that I could help. please consider upvoting and accepting my answer. cheers